# Centering An Image In CSS

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out how to center this image on my mobile website.

Here is the code I am using, I am a beginner in CSS so I'm sure this is an easy fix. Just need some help. Thanks

```
#emotion-header-img {
    display:none;
}
#emotion-header {
    height:100px !important;
    background-image:url("http://u.jimdo.com/www36/o/se9b04d2fd0388f99/emotion/orig/header.png") !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    background-size:contain !important;
}
```

Comment: First, what does the relevant HTML look like? Second, do you want it centered vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the element to be centered horizontally and vertically as well:

`/* generated from howtocenterincss.com, personally tried and tested! */`

```css
#emotion-header {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        /* height:100px !important; no need for this if you don't want to limit size*/
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
        background-size:contain !important;
}

#emotion-header-img {
  
        height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="emotion-header">
  <img id="emotion-header-img" src="http://u.jimdo.com/www36/o/se9b04d2fd0388f99/emotion/orig/header.png" alt="image header" \>
 </div>
```

Of course there are many many other possibilities, and **things get complicated** when you want to add support for old browsers like IE7 or IE8. On anything before IE11 you would need to use a table cell. **The above code snippet works for IE11 and mordern browsers.**

**A relevant and good resource** I've found when trying to center things in CSS is [howtocenterincss.com](http://howtocenterincss.com), which generates the right CSS for you based on your settings and choices. In fact, contrary to the name of the web app, it handles all sorts of alignments too. Just note that the generated code is to be embedded inside HTML elements with the `<style>` tag, which you can just extract whatever is inside those style tags and move to a CSS file for use.

Answer (score 0):

So you mean want to align the `background-image`? If right, you can use `background-position`. Example:

```css
#emotion-header {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-image: url("http://u.jimdo.com/www36/o/se9b04d2fd0388f99/emotion/orig/header.png");
  background-size: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="emotion-header"></div>
```